# itextsharp getbookmarks() truncates large titles

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to extract the bookmarks of a pdf and then split the pdf using them.
Now, One of the bookmarks has a 276 character long title but the "Title" key of the dictionary has the first 264 characters only.
How do I overcome this issue?

The version of itextsharp is 2.0.50727

**Edit**
Having the same issue with 5.4.2

Comment: The version of iTextSharp is too old to look at the problem.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie facing the same issue in 5.4.2 also